# When should I use user_load($user->uid)

Tags: commerce, users

when do we need to load user using  user_load($user->uid) after global $user. Why do we need to load a user because we can access user data after declaring it global. I am adding a commerce customer to his billing and shipping profiles, should I use user_load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global `$user` object is just the bare data received from the `users` table for the associated user. It doesn't have any field, or other module-added data, attached to it by default.

For example, if you have a field attached to your user accounts called 'field_nickname', and you want to inspect the value of that field for the current user in code, you would need to call `user_load()` for the data to be available.

```
// Might work, but it's not guaranteed - depends on the modules 
// you have installed and what's happened in the page build so far
$account = $GLOBALS['user'];
if ($items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_nickname')) {
  // ...
}

// Will always work.
$account = user_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);
if ($items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_nickname')) {
  // ...
}
```

There are situations when other modules will load the field and other module data onto the global `$user` object, so depending on what modules you have installed you call to `user_load()` might not strictly be necessary.

However, it's good practice to make sure you load the object yourself; if another module has already run it for the current user then that data is statically cached, so you don't get a performance hit.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do user_load() on global $user.

global $user is already a loaded user (the current user).

use user_load() when you want to load users other than the current user. for example, if you have a uid for the author of a node or comment, or a uid from a commerce order, then you use user_load() to load the user object.

Unless (as Clive mentioned), you need to access fields attached to the user, in which case you should load it.

Also, if you want profile2 fields you will need to do

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user, 'PROFILE_NAME');
```

Comment: That's not strictly true...field data isn't available by default on the global `$user` object for example - it needs to go through `user_load()` (which in turn invokes `field_attach_load()`) for that to happen

Comment: True, I was also going to mention things like profile2, and the fact that if you want profile2 fields they have to be separately loaded.